# Can usb power a 40W led light?

Tags: led, usb, usb-device, light

I've recently came across some usb led grow lights that are rated up to 40W. My question is how does a regular usb 2.0 or even 3.0 be able to power it? Is it a scam?

Comment: It might not be a scam but your misunderstanding. You could post a link to the product to clear it though

Comment: It depends on the connector, not USB data transfer version. 65W laptop chargers are common.

Comment: 40W or 40W equivalent incandescence marketing spec

Comment: Here's one I found: https://a.co/d/dYYHbG8. Yeah I'm mostly curious whether a normal cheap usb connector(most likely the one that product is using) is capable of carrying that load. If it can, does any type of those newer smartphone quickcharge power brick or laptop charger (as you mentioned) power it?

Comment: It is possible to get USB-PD supplies that can output 40W or even more.  However, the reason these cheap 5W USB supplies are included is that they are the cheapest option available, not because USB makes any sense in a grow light. Real 40W or 100W lights will include a dedicated LED driver with integrated mains power supply, which is both more cost effective and more logical for a higher powered device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're claiming "40W incandescent equivalent", which is common nonsense on Amazon, eBay, etc where the actual power is exaggerated by roughly 10-fold.  USB powered grow lights are universally junk.

You did not ask this, but if you are planning to grow more than 1 or 2 plants per year, the cost of grow lights tends to be dominated by the cost of power, so in the long term the upfront cost of the lights will become insignificant.  Do not buy anything that does not quote a umol/j figure of at least 2.0.  If they don't quote anything, it will almost certainly be cheaper to buy something better in the long term, often much cheaper.

Comment: How are you certain, as there is no link to any product in the question?

Comment: @Justme The 40W value specifically gives it away.  This is a specific class of nonsense OEM product online. For whatever reason these LEDs with a 5V/1A USB charger are marked as 40W or 75W.

Comment: I think you're right, I have a supposedly 10W version, the light output is the same whether I plug it into a 5v 0.5a usb port or a 5v 2.0a usb charger